# Azure B2C injects different html despite LoadUri having the same html content

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using custom policies and all is working great except that I do not understand the following wierd behavior of the injected html. I am working on a password reset flow and adapted the starterpack.

In a `ContentDefinition` and indpendent from the layout version (here 2.1.2, but the problem occurs also for 2.1.0)

```
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.2</DataUri>
```

I get a different injected html based only on whether I use the default page

```
<LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
```

or my custom one,

```
<LoadUri>https://mytenant.blob.core.windows.net/b2cweb/selfasserted.html</LoadUri>
```

But **this custom page contains excatly the same html as the AzureBlue one**. Specifically,
I navigated to the page `/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml` , copied the html content and pasted it in my custom file in blobstorage.

**Expected result**

I expect the html page where the id="api" div is injected to be exactly the same if I call the LoadUri one or two. Nothing else in the custom policy files is changed.

**Result**

1. If I use the default `LoadUri`, the cancel button is shown just below the div id="api", as expected for a proper html document format

[image]

2. If I use my custom page, which again contains the same html but lives in blobstorage, the cancel button appears below the continue button in the html (but is rendered on top via css absolute positioning)

[image]

Also notice the appeareance of an empty div with class="buttons" at the beginning of the div id="api".

I need to understand what is happening for the purpose of understanding and ideally I would like the generated cancel button to appear just like the default AzureBlue.

I checked out that the old, classic userflow puts the button at the bottom, so it is as if I am using version 1.2.0 but only for my custom page, whereas my content definition is always 2.1.2 or 2.1.1.

Comment: Thanks @Octopus and I would recommend to use the custom page as defined by you to avoid the rendering issue. Azure B2C policy engine and page layout are tightly coupled. Please follow the page layout versions changes in the document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to the question. If I use my custom page I get a different injection whereas initially I use the same html  that hosts the div id="api". Is that expected  to have a different rendering while I use the same page layout in both cases? Please provide more information. I have been through the docs extensively already.

Comment: This is expected because of policy engine and location of storage with predefined CORS server and corresponding linked metadata files for rendering.So please use as best practices provided in the document.

Comment: If you post an answer I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Jit_MSFT Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Octopus and please find the same response here.

This is expected because of policy engine and location of storage with predefined CORS server and corresponding linked metadata files for rendering. So please use as best practices provided in the document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout